# Monix. Как обрабатывать ошибки в методе .mapParallelUnordered

Tags: scala, реактивное-программирование

Я спроектировал реактивный поток, в котором могут встречаться невалидные элементы. По задумке, поток должен просто пропускать их. Для этого я использую `Observable.empty`. К примеру:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    .flatMap(i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) {   // Bad i
        Observable.empty
      } else
        Observable.pure(i)
    )
    .foreachL(i => print(s"Good i: $i"))   /*Output: Good i: 1
                                                     Good i: 3
                                                     Good i: 5
                                                     Good i: 7
                                                     Good i: 9*/
```

Это код в принципе работает, правда элементы обрабатывает последовательно. Но у меня активно используются долгие IO операции, поэтому решено было рефакторить с `.mapParallelUnordered`. Получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    .mapParallelOrdered(3)(i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        Task.raiseError(new Exception(s"Bad i: $i"))
      } else
        Task.pure(i)
    )
    .foreachL(i => print(s"Good i: $i"))    /*Output: Good i: 1*/
```

Проблема в том, что `Task.raiseError...` убивает весь поток, из-за чего тот останавливается на первом четном числе.

Как во втором случае можно пропустить все остальные шаги реактивного потока(а-ля `Observable.empty`) для невалидных элементов, сохранив при этом исполнение потока?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть будет пример чуть понагляднее.

Есть серьезная задача, которая долго думает и потенциально может упасть с ошибкой:

```scala
def process(x: Long): Task[Long] = Task.eval {
  println(s"Start processing $x")
  Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(2000))

  val result =
    if (x % 2 != 0) throw new Error(s"Error $x is odd")
    else x

  println(s"Finish processing $x")
  result
}
```

Для каждого элемента выполняем задачу, оборачиваем результаты в `Observable`, получаем `Observable[Observable[Long]]` с неупорядоченными результатами и схлопываем до `Observable[Long]`.

```
val result: Observable[Long] =
  Observable.range(1, 10)
    .mapParallelUnordered(10) { x =>
      process(x).transform(Observable.pure, _ => Observable.empty)
    }.flatten
```

Вместо простого `transform` можно обработать ошибки, перезапустить задачу и т.д.

```scala
process(x)
  .map(Observable.pure)
  .onErrorRestart(2)
  .onErrorRecover {
    case NonFatal(ex) =>
      println(ex)
      Observable.empty
  }
```